# is 'urge' politeness?

Tags: single-word-requests

How could I politely push someone to do something? Is ***urge*** an appropriate word in this sentence?

> I will really appreciate if I could receive the results earlier, could you please help me urge them to give me the results?

May I use the word ***urge*** in this sentence? Other comments about this sentence are welcome.

Comment: To urge is polite.

Comment: Sometimes, when something is _urgent_ enough, it's impolite to dissemble. If that's the case, say what you mean; _urge_ is exactly the right word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option that might seem less forceful is ***encourage***, as in:

> I would really appreciate *it* if I could *get* the results earlier.  Could you please help me ***encourage*** them to give me the results?

(Other edits in *italics*)

From the Oxford Living Dictionaries:

> ***[encourage](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/encourage)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Give support, confidence, or hope to (someone)
>
>    *‘we were encouraged by the success of this venture’*
>
>    1.1 *[with object and infinitive]* Persuade (someone) to do or continue to do something by giving support and advice.
>
>    *‘pupils are encouraged to be creative’*
>
>    1.2 Stimulate the development of (an activity, state, or belief)
>
>    *‘the intention is to encourage new writing talent’*

Note especially definitions 1.1 and 1.2.